# Not able to receive sound from my laptop unless wearing earphones

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I don't know what has happened to my Windows 7, but I am not able to hear any volume until I wear earphones. The hearing device is Speaker. Another thing is that when I don't wear earphones and open anything like YouTube then it shows like this

[image]

If I am not wrong this means that the sound is getting produced, but I am not able to hear it still. I have to wear an earphone to hear any sound from the laptop however the earphone is little damaged now, so I wanted to hear sound from the speaker only. The speaker of my computer is in-built. I have set the voice too at good level that I can hear.

[image]

So as you can see the amount of sound coming has been set high by me. Another thing is that like when I wear earphones and choose the sound giving speaker as Speakers/HP the sound can be heard without earphone too but sometimes the sound is loud sometimes mere however this voice is doesn't come now as my earphone are damaged. I don't want to buy a new earphone as already many earphones have been damaged by me. Maybe there might be some small mistake by me like once I was getting disturbed because of text cursor scrolling me down but then I realized that I had turned on the caret browsing so similarly maybe there might be a small mistake here too.

[image]

As you can see these all are speakers of my computer and I am not able to hear any until I wear a well working earphone. I also tried running the troubleshoot but it showed that there is no error the device is working fine. I tried uninstalling and then again installing the drivers but in vain.

[image]

These are the speakers device present in my device manager. And from the first image you can see that my sound is not muted.

[image]

[image]

Even I have tried also tried updating my BIOS system but in vain. So please can anyone help me resolve this problem? Let me specify you that this is some software problem according to me because if speakers weren't working then how would wearing working earphones made the speaker work but as soon as you plug off the earphones the speakers don't work. Pls don't suggest to buy me a speaker like [These](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb%20speaker%20for%20laptop&crid=1SDZCYJZWM92M&sprefix=usb%20speaker%20%2Caps%2C467&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-a-p_8_12) as I frequently take my laptop from one place to another so working with carrying speakers from one place to another would be quite difficult for me. Plus using external speakers at work doesn't seem a good idea. My laptop also gets connected to a Bluetooth but Bluetooth doesn't give any voice however the Bluetooth gives voice with other laptops and devices. So pls suggest me how to resolve this software issues? Or do you still think it is a hardware issue? I know this is a duplicate question like https://superuser.com/questions/1621106/not-able-to-receive-sound-from-my-laptop-unless-wearing-earphone but in that no one was answering and having less number of reputation I could not risk my reputation by starting bounties so that is why I asked a duplicate question. Apologies for grammar mistakes

Comment: Did you try booting thru using some Live Linux and checking again if the behavior is same or not? Live Linux will run off USB and RAM and will not install anything on the hard drive. You can even try some third party Windows PE based Live Windows 8/10 Discs as well to test it out.

Comment: Something is wrong here in your question, apart of being too large and bit pointless. I mean it miss context. Are you using bluetooth speakers? Besides problems like this is almost always related to two things 1. Speaker is damaged and 2. You need to install proprietary drivers *not Microsoft database drivers*. Hope it helps!

Comment: @patkim is Live Linux any app which I need to install? Can u give details on it? I am on window 7 and installing windows 8 and 10 might be of high cost

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø the speakers are in built and not damaged

Comment: Can it be possible that the speakers are muted somewhere from where I can't find and while wearing working earphone they get unmuted

Comment: No very much! More like if you install wrong driver that will happen. This is why you should find if this is a propertary driver and install the original **driver not** *Windows 10* *based*. As well you can try to force and install Realtek driver --> it needs a whole new step > it may work or even damage your speakers. For me never happened, but I was able to see some changes when I installed DTS proprietary audio. So you may try this trick as well

Comment: Live Linux or Third Party Windows PE based boot discs are ISO distributions using which you create a bootable Live OS USB stick or burn it to a DVD and boot your computer thru it. It runs off USB/DVD and does not install anything to Hard Disk. e.g. Mint https://www.linuxmint.com/download.php Running such live discs sometimes is useful to test the issue if it reoccurs with another Live OS or not.

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø can you share the link to install DTS proprietary audio

Comment: @Jitendra Singh I tried to find the offical website of that modded version but couldn't. Just giving one or two links, but try to reach to the official (even though is forbidden to share those types of content in Stackoverflow since it breaks DTS patterns). [Link1](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/unlocked-realtek-hd-audio-drivers-for-windows-10-dolby-digital-live-dts-interactive.228612/page-11) [link2](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6sr7_0qMXk8).

Comment: @Jitendra Singh Notice that those are modified Realtek drivers, and this third one idk if is the modified R2 version but will share it anyway [link3](https://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=353&func=fileinfo&id=686&lang=en) Notice that you should restart after installing the R2 version or any other, before DTS because you will want to fix the issue

Comment: @JitendraSingh please update your question and clarify that you can hear audio through your speakers only after connecting (and disconnecting?) your headphones. Remove the other mentions of Bluetooth and external speakers, as it's long, confusing, and non-germane.

Also, please update it to include your laptop make and model.

Comment: Has the speakers on this laptop ever worked? If yes, when they stopped working do you remember if the laptop was dropped or you updated something around that time?

Comment: Yes they used to work. After setting the voice to 24 bit 192000 hz after that some days after voice stopped coming.  Now setting the voice to its original format is also not working so i guess some other fault is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you have a HP/IDT program, I'd check the settings there. If you don't have this program I'd suggest you download the audio driver or audio SW from HP. If you have the laptop model I can help you find the driver. These SW programs usually have a pop-up prompt when you plug in a headphones/external-speaker so have a lot of various settings I am thinking could help your situation

***--edit, EliteBook 8570p audio driver:***
https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-elitebook-8570p-notebook-pc/5212912/swItemId/ob-115135-2

Comment: In addition, check the keyboard for a function key combo option to enable/disable mute/speakers.

Notebooks often detect the impedence of headphones when they're plugged in to disable the speakers and route audio to the headphones when they are plugged in. It seems that the mux is stuck with a mute setting on the speakers, but moving the audio to the headphones and back unsticks the mute. This may be done with software or firmware.

Comment: I have inserted the laptop model in the question. Now can you guide which driver to install

Comment: Sadly that 'System' screenshot doesn't like the model. I'd suggest getting it from the bottom of your laptop and/or providing the serial number (S/N). You can also get S/N with this command: ‘wmic bios list brief‘. If a comment or answer has helped you be sure to upvote them to show people you appreciate their help

Comment: Inserted S/N number in question end

Comment: 5CB3020G89 under HP warranty check page indicates it's a EliteBook 8570p. Will update my answer with driver link. https://support.hp.com/us-en/checkwarranty

Comment: @gregg Can you confirm by seeing the question again or https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPCir.png because I guess have these drivers only which you have sent the link of

Comment: I see your picture. These drivers could be newer and/or they could include the audio program I said. Did you try to install them? If it says you already have drivers, I suggest you uninstall IDT, check box to remove drivers/SW, reboot, then install the HP downloaded file

Comment: Sounds similar to your issue: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/IDT-High-Definition-Audio-Codec/td-p/5588736

Comment: Good thing now the voice is coming but it is very low. I checked the laptop speakers by opening the laptop there was nothing there stuck in speaker and the voice is also full. Will later show the comparison between the speaker voice coming and earphone voice coming

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xFgc.png the voice comparison

Comment: Pls tell @ gregg what to do next the voice has started coming but it is so less than it can't be heared. Check the laptop and there is nothing stuck in it. Am awarding bounty to you but pls help what to do next

Comment: What changed that fixed it so low voice can be heard? Is the issue the volume is low? If so have you tried adjusting the volume via buttons on laptop, Windows Settings, IDT audio app? Your picture seems to show you have headphones & speakers plugged in, try to use only one to see if volume is improved. Windows Settings allows you to adjust volume per device & per app, please see if this guide helps you: https://www.howtogeek.com/352787/how-to-set-per-app-sound-outputs-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once. After a lot of effort, I realized that the audio jack in my computer was damaged. This made the audio drive believe that I always had my headset connected, so I could only hear the audio when using them.

I was able to solve this by disabling the audio jack from the configuration panel for the driver.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

When you hear sound using earphone then I think your built-in speaker or their connection is damaged

Comment: Well after I plug in the earphones(if they are working properly) then even without wearing earphone sound comes. If speakers had fault so why would speakers work after wearing earphone

Answer (score -1):

To begin with, setting your default device sample rate to a value greater than 48 kHz is almost always pointless. In fact, it will actually *reduce* the audio quality out of the speakers, because Windows is interpolating between the source material (typically 44.1 KHz for YouTube, Spotify, Netflix, etc) and the 192 KHz you have set. If you have high-resolution music (TIDAL MQA, FLAC, etc) then you should set your media player in dedicated mode so it can adjust the output frequency to be equal to the source (often 88.1 KHz).

Setting the output format to extreme values such as 192 KHz can also cause issues such as (surprise surprise) no output through speakers.

To start with, restore the output format to 16 bit, 44.1 KHz and use the **Test** button in the same window to test the output. Assuming you have the correct drivers installed, and don't have an errant program messing with your speaker output, it should work if your speakers and soundcard aren't damaged.

Comment: Well that didn't work as well as I would like to you check my edit

Comment: I just read through the post again, I don't see where you have said that you tried setting the Format back to 44.1 KHz? To be clear, I am talking about this page here https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtXGs.png

Comment: If your speakers are making sound, but it is really quiet, I think it is likely they are physically damaged rather than a software (Windows) issue. As a last attempt, you could try uninstalling all the sound drivers and using Windows Update to install the default Microsoft drivers. Also make sure that the speaker grills are not covered or blocked.

Comment: I just read that "it will cause interpolation"? Because it will not! Never heard about upmixing. Microsoft has announced this feature decades ago!